# Is it possible to authenticate with bind on ldap using the "username" in a webflux application with spring security like in php?

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have searched on google but I always find only methods using the dn but for the login I don't have the dn and the username is not part of the dn. I also have looked into the code and the various different errors I have encountered and I have found nothing so far.

```
2020-03-11 12:21:26.718 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] Completed 302 FOUND, headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:21:26.719 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [0b7f4a17] Handling completed
2020-03-11 12:21:26.730 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] HTTP GET "/login", headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:21:26.734 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:21:26.734 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [0b7f4a17] Handling completed
2020-03-11 12:21:27.331 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] HTTP GET "/favicon.ico", headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:21:27.336 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] Completed 302 FOUND, headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:21:27.337 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [0b7f4a17] Handling completed
2020-03-11 12:21:27.341 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] HTTP GET "/login", headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:21:27.345 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:21:27.345 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [0b7f4a17] Handling completed
2020-03-11 12:22:33.067 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] HTTP POST "/login", headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:22:33.092 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.http.codec.FormHttpMessageReader     : [0b7f4a17] Read form fields [username, password, _csrf] (content masked)
2020-03-11 12:22:33.103 DEBUG 26996 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider
2020-03-11 12:22:33.106 DEBUG 26996 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.s.l.a.LdapAuthenticationProvider     : Processing authentication request for user: <username that worked in php>
2020-03-11 12:22:33.131 TRACE 26996 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] Completed 302 FOUND, headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:22:33.132 TRACE 26996 --- [oundedElastic-1] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [0b7f4a17] Handling completed
2020-03-11 12:22:33.142 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] HTTP GET "/login?error", headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:22:33.146 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.w.s.adapter.HttpWebHandlerAdapter    : [0b7f4a17] Completed 200 OK, headers={masked}
2020-03-11 12:22:33.146 TRACE 26996 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.h.s.r.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter      : [0b7f4a17] Handling completed
```

that's the log output with trace enabled when I try to login.

Comment: Hi Minecraftschurli. You made a comment, `I also have looked into the code and the various different errors I have encountered`, It would help others looking at your question if you could post the errors you are seeing in addition to the question. To post the errors, click the edit link and copy/paste what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how! I needed to use `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` instead of `LdapAuthenticationProvider` with `BindAuthenticator`.